# Entity Framework store XML datatype ; "Unable to switch encoding" error

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework version 6.0.0 in a C# Project that uses .NET Framework 4.5. I have a class `Filing` who has a SQL Server column `XmlContent` which is `xml` datatype. I have Database-first Entity Framework I am using primarily to **save** rows to the `Filing` table (I **currently don't read** those rows back, if that makes a difference)

I've read these posts regarding a "string" backing property to save to an XML column using Entity Framework, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5150706/1175496) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a2e6aa49-f573-4dca-a1e7-505841c3c668/entity-framework-treats-xml-type-in-sql-server-as-a-string?forum=adodotnetentityframework#a55a01f8-b16d-4786-9c74-00ca527df3ba)

My XML declaration looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
....
```

And my Entity Framework auto-generated (database-first) looks like this:

```
public partial class Filing
{
    // ...
    public string XmlContent { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

With my custom partial class like this (saving to the string property...):

```
public partial class Filing
{
    [NotMapped]
    public XmlDocument XmlDocument
    {
        get
        {
            var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.LoadXml(this.XmlContent);
            return xmlDocument;

        }
        set
        {
            this.XmlContent = value.OuterXml;
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

When I do this:

```
eFileEntities.Filings.Add(filingWithUtf8XmlString);
eFileEntities.SaveChanges();
```

I get an exception, whose InnerException (eventually), reads:

```
"XML Parsing : line 1 , character 38, unable to switch the encoding."
```

I've read these posts regarding the error I'm getting, "unable to switch the encoding"

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8998183/1175496
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091209/751158

  - These answers suggest using a `SqlXml` datatype, so there is no need to bother about encodings. **But I don't know how to do that [in the context of Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760788/how-to-solve-unable-to-switch-the-encoding-error-when-inserting-xml-into-sql-s/8998183#comment52750753_8998183)**
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/385756/1175496
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1564803/1175496

  - If I change XML declaration to use `encoding="utf-16"` as these answers suggests, EntityFramework can `saveChanges()`  with no errors, **but I want to avoid (if possible)**:

    - Changing encodings
    - Stripping the declaration (even though I understand [SQL Server doesn't store the declaration anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9002485/1175496))

Any ideas?

Comment: did you manage to find the solution?

Comment: Nope, I am still manually changing `encoding="utf-16"`

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. Is there a way to support this in EF without have to revert back to ADO.NET?