# ASP.NET MVC entity framework alternative

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET mvc.
Is there a good alternative for entity framework in for MVC?

Comment: Alternative that does what exactly?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC doesn't care about which ORM you choose, or if you do choose an ORM or do Micro ORMS, or plain old DataSets, hence I think this is a possible duplicate of [.net ORM Comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101974/net-orm-comparison)

Comment: .NET ORMs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) you want with MVC.

A popular choice is [nHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx), though there are [many many more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#.NET).

---

Other popular alternatives (some commercial) are:

- [Castle ActiveRecord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_ActiveRecord#)
- [LLBLGen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLBLGen_Pro)
- [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL)
- [SubSonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubSonic_%28software%29)

StackOverflow uses their own in-house (now open sourced), micro-ORM, [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/).

Comment: can you list a few, for example what do the stackoverflow use?

Comment: I am converting my website from asp.net to mvc. should i use an ORM at all, or should i just work directly with the DB?

Comment: @user563823 - Only you can answer that. ORMs are an abstraction over databases, whether you need one or not is your decision.

Comment: on the one hand, i like to have full control over my DB and on the other hand, I don't want to duplicate the data scheme and maintain data consistency between the DB and the model. How can i combine them